# What this lines in bubble sort algorithm means?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

In Introduction to programming with C++ 6th edition book, it explain the bubble sort algorithm with C++ and i understand it, but there is two lines of code I'm not understand why they in the code, when I tried to understand code I erase them and nothing changed and the algorithm still working.
So I still confused about them.
there is the code;

```
int main()
 {
     int numbers[4] = {23, 46, 12, 35};
     int sub = 0; //keeps track of subscripts
     int temp = 0; //variable used for swapping
     int maxSub = 3; //maximum subscript
     int lastSwap = 0; //position of last swap
     char swap = 'Y'; //indicates if a swap was made

     //repeat loop instructions as long as a swap was made
     while (swap == 'Y')
     {
     swap = 'N'; //assume no swaps are necessary

     sub = 0; //begin comparing with first
     //array element

     //compare adjacent array elements to determine
     //compare adjacent array elements to determine
     //whether a swap is necessary
     while (sub < maxSub)
     {
         if (numbers[sub] > numbers[sub + 1])
         {
             //a swap is necessary
             temp = numbers[sub];
             numbers[sub] = numbers[sub + 1];
             numbers[sub + 1] = temp;
             swap = 'Y';
             lastSwap = sub;
         } //end if
         sub += 1; //increment subscript
         } //end while

         maxSub = lastSwap; //reset maximum subscript
     } //end while

     //display sorted array
     for (int x = 0; x < 4; x += 1)
        cout << numbers[x] << endl;
     //end for

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 } //end of main function
```

so I don't understand `lastSwap = sub` & `maxSub = lastSwap`.
are they important or I'm right about erase them from the code?
can anyone explain to it to me.

Comment: If you don't want to change anything else in you code other than that two line. Then those two lines are necessary. But removing those line are possible if we rewrite the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple,

1st pass of Bubble Sort => Maximum element in array gets the new appropriate position.

2nd pass => Second maximum element in array gets the new appropriate position.

.

.

.

Nth pass => Nth element in array gets the new appropriate position.

Variable `lastSwap` stores the maximum index of the array where the last swapping occurred.

**Now, if for the first pass, the new appropriate position is not the last index of the array, that is, `lastSwap < last index of array`, then it means that the array after the index `lastSwap` is already sorted and we don't need to process it.**

This is followed for each pass and **upper bound on total number of passes(`maxSub`)** is set to `lastSwap`, thus reducing the number of passes.

**Advantages of using those 2 lines:**

1. We optimised the number of passes when the array gets sorted before the completion of all passes.
2. It can also detect if the given / input array is sorted or not, in the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are there for performance (making it run faster), not for correctness.  So removing those lines will make it run slower, but will not make it fail to sort correctly.

After the function does a swap, it has bubbled the highest value seen so far up to numbers[sub + 1].  If after that, it doesn't find anything more to swap, that means that the rest of the array already has the highest values in sorted order, so the function does not need to look at them again--all those numbers are already at their correct final sorted positions in the array.  So for every swap, the function saves the array position in lastSwap, so at the end of the inner while loop, lastSwap contains the location where the last swap was made and the function stores this value in maxSub.

Then the outer while loop starts another scan from the beginning of the array with sub set to zero.  But now maxSub has changed, so the inner loop

`while (sub < maxSub)`

only goes up to maxSub and doesn't needlessly scan the rest of the array, which must already have the highest values in sorted order.

This speed difference will not be noticeable on an array of four numbers, but with enough numbers to sort, saving the useless work will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt contribute to correctness of the algorithm instead its there to improvise the speed of bubble sort algorithm .
The statement stores the value of largest bubble read so far hence doesn't go beyond that loop.
For better understanding go through how bubble sort actually works.

Comment: Thank you, Could you please tell me a good source for learning bubble sort?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-9/